# How to setup AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB) with TLS termination for Grpc service running in EKS?

Tags: grpc, amazon-eks, http2, tls1.3, aws-nlb

I'm using AWS Load Balancer Controller for setup AWS NLB with TLS termination for Grpc service (grpc-dotnet implementation) running in EKS. Traffic between NLB and Pod in EKS is unencrypted. I also tried to set it up in UI but it ends with same result. The k8s service with annotation for NLB configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-path: /health
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 'true'
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb-ip
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:account:certificate/my-cert-arn"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "9090"
        # service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-alpn-policy: HTTP2Preferred
    name: grpc-api-svc
    namespace: default
spec:
    ports:
        - 
            port: 9090
            protocol: TCP
            targetPort: 9090
    selector:
        app: grpc-api
    type: LoadBalancer
```

The configuration route traffic from NLB to my Grpc Api, but requests end with error:

```json
{
  "created": "@1678456920.910000000",
  "description": "Failed to pick subchannel",
  "file": "src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc",
  "file_line": 5391,
  "referenced_errors": [
    {
      "created": "@1678456920.909000000",
      "description": "failed to connect to all addresses",
      "file": "src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc",
      "file_line": 398,
      "grpc_status": 14
    }
  ]
}
```

When I remove TLS termination (SSL part) it works well.

I also tried to add ALPN
`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-alpn-policy: HTTP2Preferred` with same result.

EDIT:
Python service work well, the issue appears only when I'm using .Net Grpc Server (grpc-dotnet)

**Root Cause:**
NLB does terminate TLS but keep in header https schema. It seems the .net server is more strict and Kestrel ignore these requests.

**Solution**
You have to set in Kestrel options

```
options.AllowAlternateSchemes = true
```